# What does $\bar{x}_{\textrm{el}}$ represent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, notation, statics, moment

In the context of centroids and moments, what do $\bar{x}_{\textrm{el}}$ and $\bar{y}_{\textrm{el}}$ represent?

For example:

$$\bar{x}L = \int \bar{x}_{\textrm{el}}dL$$

Some references that use this notation:

- http://www.sut.ac.th/engineering/Civil/CourseOnline/430201/pdf/05_review.pdf

  - (page 1)
- *Vector Mechanics for Engineers:Statics and Dynamics* by Ferdinand P. Beer & E. Russell Johnston Jr.

  - an example from their solution's manual:
    [image: *Vector Mechanics for Engineers:Statics and Dynamics*]

Comment: This is not a physics question... You are asking us to explain your textbook's notation to you...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but could it be the position vector of the element?